# OnTouch history size always 0

Tags: android, touch, history

I'm trying to make simple direction recognition in onTouchListener in my view, but event.getHistorySize() return 0, or sometimes, but rarely 1 or 2. Generally speaking, there's no history so i can't do the recognition

```
    ll3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                if (arg1.getHistorySize() > 0) {
                    int prev = (int) arg1.getHistoricalY((arg1
                            .getHistorySize() - 1));
                    if (arg1.getY() > prev) {
```

Does any one know where the problem is?

Comment: save the history you need yourself in some kind of queue, you get all the history you need via `onTouch`. The history will only be filled if there were multiple touchevents between this and the prior call to `onTouch`. It's not intended to contain all the history

Comment: Don't you need a gesture listener then? You need to handle this history yourself, or use such a special listener. Check some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this unless you have a good reason for looking at every value the sensor outputs. (Values outputted in between frames might be less important?)

```
ll3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    int prevY=0;
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getY() > prevY) { 
               // do stuff
            }
            prevY = arg1.getY();
```